# How to take userid or email input and validate in servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, authentication

My question is simple. In some websites it is seen one can enter the site providing his/her email-id or userid and password(i.e already registered with the site). Now in MVC structure we use servlet as **DECISION CONTROLLER**. So after taking the input in servlet, we can compare them with `userid` or `email-id` column of `user` table. So to take input we can write in servlet:

```
String input=request.getParameter("inputfield");
```

After taking the input what should be the way to check ,if the given input is `email-id` or `userid`? Should we compare the String `input` with  each value of both the `userid` and `emailid` column of `user` table? If that is the only way the program quality will be very low and security can be exploited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email ids have specific syntax...

So use Regular expression to detect email pattern.

If the pattern matches (meaning email id is valid) fire

```
SELECT email FROM user
```

else

```
SELECT username FROM user
```

Simple :)

Comment: This is wonderful website to learn and try regular expressions http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ You can find standard regular expressions for emails too.

Comment: Pranab What is `regular expression`?

Comment: google it... Its a VERY VERY VERY powerful way to perform string operations. They have weird syntax but they are beautiful and powerful as well.